# open/close li (or html element) every X iterations

Tags: php, html

I have a list of items (clients) that I want to loop,
but I want every 5 to be in an `<li>` tag, and in case the last tag has less than 5 (2 for example), it would automatically close.

I did the following code, which works, but how can I optimize it, especially the last part?

```
foreach ($clients AS $k=>$client){
    $liopen ='';
    if ($k % 5 == 0){ 
        echo "<li>\n";
        $liopen = true; // we have an opened an li tag
    }
    echo '<div class="item" style="background:url('.$client['image'].') center center no-repeat;"></div>'."\n";

    if ( $k == 4 || $k == 9 || $k == 14 || $k == 19 || $k == 24 || $k == 29 || $k == 34 || $k == 39 || $k == 44 || $k == 49 || $k == 54 || $k == 59 || $k == 64 || $k == 69 ){ 
        echo "</li>\n";
        $liopen = false;
    }
}

if ($liopen == true) { // if an li tag is still open , close it
    echo "</li>\n";
    $liopen = false;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean 'optimize' ? This shouldn't be too heavy on any system, so unless you need that extra microsecond, I doubt this is about performance? but what it is about?

Comment: @Nanne: I assumed it's about making the code cleaner.

Comment: roy naufal, Check my answer.

Comment: thanks for the comments and quick replies ... and yes, it's just for making the code neater (specially that last condition, couldn't figure out the arithmetic i needed for the modulus)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's kind of strange that your `<li>` elements are broken up this way, since there doesn't seem to be any semantic difference between clients that fit in different groups... I'd probably put each client in an `<li>` and then use css to do whatever it is you're trying to accomplish with the groupings... but that wasn't really the question.

To do it your way, you can use [`array_chunk`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) to break the clients into groups of 5 (or fewer for the last one):

```
$groups = array_chunk($clients, 5);
foreach ($groups as $group) {
  echo "<li>\n";
  foreach ($group as $client) {
      echo '<div class="item" style="background:url('.$client['image'].') center center no-repeat;"></div>'."\n";
  }
  echo "</li>\n";
}
```

*Also*: If you decide to stick with your implementation, you could use modular arithmetic (as you did with `$k % 5 == 0`) for the other case as well. So this line:

```
if ( $k == 4 || $k == 9 || $k == 14 || $k == 19 || ...
```

could be replaced with

```
if ( $k % 5 == 4 ) {
```

Comment: i have them broken up this way because using a certain slider plugin, and i need them grouped in that way, otherwise i'll have to recode the plugin ... thanks for the solution, exactly what i needed!

Answer (score 0):

**Replace** your code with the following-

```
foreach ($clients AS $k=>$client)
{
    if ($k % 5 == 0)
    echo "<li><br>";

    echo '<div class="item" style="background:url('.$client['image'].') center center no-repeat;"></div>'."<br>";
}

echo "</li>";
```

This will work because the opening of `<li>` tag will automatically close the previous `<li>` tag so you basically need only one `</li>` at the end of your **clients**-list irrespective of the no of remaining clients in the last group.

## Try it...

Comment: thanks, look neat too...but i prefer to have the lis closed inside the code as well

Comment: @roynaufal Then I have to think something else to solve the problem.